# Binormal and Tangent with Normal Mapping

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to make a normal mapping shader for my DirectX meshes, and while following some notes from my school, it tells me that I need my vertex structure to contain a Vec3 for Pos and a 3x3 Martix for the normal, binormal and the tangent, but I can't figure out how to get the binormal and the tangent. I referenced my book, which told me to use the D3DXComputeTangentFrameEx function, however all my meshes are D3DXFRAME objects, not an ID3DXMesh*..

Can anyone help me out?

I also want to add, I have the pos and the normal vectors already.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [D3DXFRAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172845), you could find `pMeshContainer` member, which is [D3DXMESHCONTAINER*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205371) type, which have `MeshData` member of [D3DXMESHDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205372) type, which have `pMesh` member of `ID3DXMesh*` type, but it is valid only if `Type == D3DXMESHTYPE_MESH`.

Example:

```
{
    D3DXFRAME Frame;

    ID3DXMesh* pMesh;

    if( Frame.pMeshContainer->MeshData.Type == D3DXMESHTYPE_MESH )
        pMesh = Frame.pMeshContainer->MeshData.pMesh;
    else
        pMesh = 0;  // model is ID3DXPatchMesh type
}
```